# Changing tick label size globally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fontsize, ticks

I am trying to change the font size of the tick labels, but they won't react to

```
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}}
```

This is because I create the tikz-file automatically from Matlab.
Hence, there are some settings for the tick labels, which somehow overwrite the font size somehow (although it is only the color).
Now, can I globally change the tick label size without having to change the automatically produced tikz-file?

Also, is there a possibility to save space while aligning the plots and labels properly? Because right now, "ylabel 4" is a little bit out of the ordinary. When I use something like

```
\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=2.5em,align=center}}
```

the structure takes relatively much space. I know this is intended by the command, but maybe someone has an elegant solution to this?

Hope you understand my question, many thanks in advance!

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\newcommand{\inputTikz}[1]{
            \setlength\figureheight{0.35\textheight} 
            \setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{#1}}}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
    every axis/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
    every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize, yshift=0.5ex}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \inputTikz{fig.tikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The tikz-file "fig.tikz" is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.39\figurewidth,
height=0.458\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0.542\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5,
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=-0.071428579543637,
ymax=2.00000022722184,
ylabel={ylabel 1},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.5,0.97)},anchor=north,legend columns=2,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0 0\\
};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.39\figurewidth,
height=0.458\figureheight,
at={(0.503\figurewidth,0.542\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5,
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=-0.0227138669391646,
ymax=0.0227138674410331,
ylabel={ylabel 2},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0 0\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.39\figurewidth,
height=0.458\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5,
xlabel={xlabel 1},
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=-0.0500000006711102,
ymax=1.40000001879109,
ylabel={ylabel 3},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.5,0.97)},anchor=north,legend columns=2,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.39\figurewidth,
height=0.458\figureheight,
at={(0.503\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5,
xlabel={xlabel 2},
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=-0.264169253617191,
ymax=0.264169281884055,
ylabel={ylabel 4},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand what you want to achieve, but to answer your questions:

**1)** Use `\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}}` instead.

**2)** You could put the y-axis ticks for the second and third plot on the right side instead and remove/decrease the horizontal separation of the plots. Use `axis y line*=right` in the options for these axes.

Depending on what your axes limits really looks like, it might or might not be a good idea to use groupplots instead of four axis environments.

Why do you use both a `resizebox` and `width=\figurewidth` when you input your figures? Imho, it would be better to just use:

```
\newcommand{\inputTikz}[1]{
            \setlength\figureheight{0.35\textheight} 
            \setlength\figurewidth{.9\textwidth} %For example .9
            \centering
            \input{#1}}
```

To avoid scaling of labels.

Here's an example of `fig.tikz` using `groupplot` instead: 
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,horizontal sep=15pt}]
\nextgroupplot[width=0.39\figurewidth,
height=0.458\figureheight,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5,
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=-0.071428579543637,
ymax=2.00000022722184,
ylabel={ylabel 1},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.5,0.97)},anchor=north,legend columns=2,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0 0\\
};
\nextgroupplot[width=0.39\figurewidth,
height=0.458\figureheight,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
axis y line*=right,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5,
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=-0.0227138669391646,
ymax=0.0227138674410331,
ylabel={ylabel 2},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0 0\\
};
\nextgroupplot[width=0.39\figurewidth,
height=0.458\figureheight,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5,
xlabel={xlabel 1},
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=-0.0500000006711102,
ymax=1.40000001879109,
ylabel={ylabel 3},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.5,0.97)},anchor=north,legend columns=2,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
};
\nextgroupplot[width=0.39\figurewidth,
height=0.458\figureheight,
scale only axis,
axis y line*=right,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5,
xlabel={xlabel 2},
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=-0.264169253617191,
ymax=0.264169281884055,
ylabel={ylabel 4},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I know that I've seen a solution that makes sure that all ylabels are equally far from the axes, can't remember where right now though. 

Label 4 is further from the axis compared to label 2 due to -0.2 having a greater width than -2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try aligning the way you proposed.
However, in your example the font size of the tick labels is still unchanged. Like I have written before, this is due to 
"every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}}"
in the tikz file which overwrites the font size setting.
I used the resizebox since without, the figure is shifted slightly to the right and overfull hboxes occur.